# Criteria for chatting

Tags: support, chat

What is the rep requirement for chatting in the following :

chat.stackexchange.com
chat.stackoverflow.com

Is it the same?
What does the 20 rep condition mean?
20 rep in which site?

Comment: In the site you're going to be chatting in. Maybe you should've done some research before asking.

Comment: What about the first website in my question?

Comment: Lamart, that's where you choose a site chatroom to begin chatting.

Comment: Maybe you should have done some research before commenting @MARamezani . Looks like its _net SE rep_ that should cross 20 to chat on _any_ of the SE sites.

Comment: No need to be sarcastic. You just answered your own question (just to make me wrong :) with a minute amount of research. Now, you should decide whether to write an answer or flag this to close or delete it already. Case closed.

Comment: Whats the use of keeping 20 rep restriction when all I have to do is join any 20 SE sites out of the many? @MARamezani

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253487/what-is-the-use-of-keeping-20-rep-restriction-in-chat

Comment: Seems like adjusting the requirement to be a minimum of 20 rep on any *one* site would be appropriate to avoid this loophole

Comment: I don't think that this is considered a loophole. I got -4. @mhlester

Comment: I think your other question starts off on the wrong foot with a title questioning a 20 rep minimum. That minimum is there for good reason. This post (which I voted up) points out that the minimum is less effective than intended. The other post (which I didn't vote on) seems to call the whole thing into question without any suggestions for why it's bad or how it could be better.

Comment: @mhlester Done. Should I change something else too?

Answer (score 3):

The requirement is that the **net** SE rep  should cross 20 to chat on **any** of the SE sites.

.....[which can be acheived easily by joining any 20 SE sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253487/what-is-the-use-of-keeping-20-rep-restriction-in-chat)