# Comments and votes for honest low reputation user

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, review, voting

I browse SE a lot. Not directly, but for most questions I put in google I get the answers in SE. Sometimes I would like to comment, or vote some questions/answers but I don't have enough reputation.

I have a few questions, but half don't have answers (probably because they are hard/impossible, and other questions I have would be duplicates), and I find it very hard to get points from answering, because when I know an answer, many other people do and are faster and better at it. I would need to be much more active (constantly refreshing unanswered list page) than I have time for.

I signed up for already 10 communities, because I wanted to up-vote some really helpful (low voted) answers, in the likes that some day I get enough reputation for them to count. I only have questions/answers in 4 of them. Now I realize I probably won't ever get the reputation in those communities.

Are there any tips for me to speed up my reputation increase?
And what about the communities that I don't expect to gain reputation at all, but would still like to vote/comment?

Comment: Are you aware of the [association bonus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/255554)?

Comment: That's very nice! That makes sense, and is more motivating :)

Comment: True, Just focus on one, and you'll be able to upvote, comment, and chat, in all the 100+ others when reaching 200 rep in the one you focused on. (actually, you can chat anywhere except MSE and SO by just having 20 accounts, but [that might be a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253487/i-was-able-to-post-in-chat-with-less-than-20-rep))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your will to help the communities here. There is no way to measure 'honest' users, so we have to keep using reputation as a measurement who gets what privilege.

In order to comment, you only need [5 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), so 1 upvoted question already gets you enough reputation. Another way to gain some reputation is by suggesting edits. If you see something to improve, just edit the post into shape. You will be rewarded with 2 reputation if your edit is being approved.

Since there is an [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/245360) (which kicks in at 200 reputation), you only have to get 200 reputation on one site. Then on all other sites you will get 100 reputation for free. Thus giving you the ability to comment, upvote, etc.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about. How could you answear in 4min? I can't make a comment in 4min x) Editing suggestions seems like a slower method. But, ok, those are my options. And I didn't know about association bonus prior to this question. You'll get your upvote when I reach 200 on tex community, hehe.

Comment: That comes with lots of experience here. And that is the same for other questions you answer. You pick up ideas and methods, and after some time you will be able to answer along with others.