# How can I answer a highly active question without enough reputation?

Tags: support, protected-questions

I have a great answer to an important question on the *[Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site, but I cannot post my findings there without a higher rep. How can I share what I know with the other folks on that question (and with countless other people who are asking the same thing)?

(Note: I have plenty of rep on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), but nothing on the Arduino site)

The question I want to answer is related to the connectors used on Grove Shields which are various expansion boards for Arduinos and other such devices. The connectors appear to be proprietary, but I've discovered they really are just uncommon in the USA.

The information I wish to contribute was researched extensively, and would help a lot of folks who are trying to find compatible connectors at affordable prices.  I have part compiled part numbers, supporting schematics, vendor options and more, and just want to share it, you know?

Can I create a new question, basically reasking the same thing, and answer it myself?  (I think this is bad form, am I right?)

Additional information:  I do not see any place to add an answer, but instead I see a box saying it is a highly active question and I need 10 reputation to answer.

[image]

I cannot post comments to it either. If I try to comment it says "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

The question:
*[What type of connector does the GROVE system use?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9030/what-type-of-connector-does-the-grove-system-use)*

*I understand that I simply cannot post answers to a protected/highly active question until I have enough rep, and that I need to gain rep in various ways before I can answer.*

Is asking a question **that has already been asked** forbidden?  If not, then I would post a new question asking for the same information, and include my own answer, for the good of the community.

Comment: Do you have enough rep to participate on the Arduino Meta / Chat?

Comment: I have no option to answer. Where the answer field would be is replaced with this banner/box saying "Highly active question. Earn 10 reputation (not counting the association bonus) in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity."

Comment: It looks that you have achieved enough rep on Arduino SE to post your answer. Congratulations.

Answer (score 4):

On Arduino SE, to remove the restrictions of new users it's required to earn reputation >= 10, that means that a single upvote on a question or answer will make you able to post your answer to the protected question. It sounds simple but on some communities ( I don't know about the specific case of Arduino SE) it could be very hard to gain the first reputation points, please be patient. Note: If you are already gained at least 20 reputation points across the SE network you might http://chat.stackexchange.com chat on any public chat room.

Regarding:

> Is asking a question that has already been asked forbidden?

Based on the Stack Exchange model, it's very likely that the question will be closed as a duplicate. If the answer to the question is really great, the new question might be merged with the old question or vice versa but the way that each case is handled depends on each community. You should ask on [Arduino Meta SE](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/) because regarding contributions to a community, it doesn't matter if you "are right" if the community don't think that.

---

Participate on [Arduino SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) to gain privileges:

- Suggest edits to improve posts
- Post new questions
- Post answers to  unprotected questions
- ...

Once you're able to participate on [Arduino Meta SE](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/), you could post a question there in order to ask for specific guidance about the protected question that you want to answer.

Once you're able to participate in [Arduino SE Chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=arduino.stackexchange.com), you could engage with Arduino chat participants to get help to learn the ropes of the site and have specific guidance about the protected question that you want to answer

Resources:

- [Arduino Privileges](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- [I was able to post in chat with less than 20 rep by joining 20 sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253487/289691)

Comment: They have reputation on Super User which on its own is enough to chat in any site room other than SO and Meta.SE rooms.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog You are right... but to remove the new user restrictions on Arduino it's only required a single upvote :)

Comment: That's not Sonic's point. Your last paragraph is misleading. It implies one must get 20 reputation on Arduino to be able to chat in its rooms, and that is wrong. 20 rep anywhere else is enough, the OP here can already join their chat rooms and talk freely. I'm not downvoting because the other parts are correct and helpful, and the last paragraph is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you would have the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/295232), you would be able to flag the question for moderator attention, stating that it needs to be unprotected in order to provide a new answer.

Many questions have been protected automatically because they attract spam answers, and that could be reapplied after you've posted your answer, or not - protecting questions can indeed reduce the need of moderation, but only to a certain extent.

This may take a while, but it's an old question - it's not like it urgently needs another answer.

Comment: I know that you participate on a lot of sites but, are you familiar with Arduino?

Comment: Does that matter? If somebody would cast a flag like that on one of the sites I moderate, I wouldn't hesitate to remove the protection. Abuse is possible, but I figure it's so rare that I'm willing to deal with any possible fallout.

Comment: They don't have the association bonus, however.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog ah, you're right. I didn't check their profile, I read "plenty of rep on superuser" and apparently I have a different idea about what constitutes "plenty of rep" ...